# Конвертировать строку в массив чисел в с#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int number = 233411;
        string Number = Convert.ToString(number);
        Console.WriteLine(Number);
        int[] Array = new int[Number.Length];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < Number.Length; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Number[i]);
            Console.Write(Array[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

233411

50 51 51 52 49 49

Почему на выходе другие числа?

Answer (score 1):

Как можно заметить, это коды символов. Дело в том, что вы передаете в ToInt32 символ, а он переводится в [код](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_) Юникода.

Надо передавать строку

```
Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Number[i].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток.

Для преобразования char в числовые типы на [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) рекомендуют использовать метод GetNumericValue.

```
Array[i] = (int)char.GetNumericValue(Number[i]);
```

Проблема появления "других" чисел в строчке

```
Array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Number[i]);
```

[Документация гласит:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_)

> The ToInt32(Char) method returns a 32-bit signed integer that
>   represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument. If
>   value is not a low surrogate or a high surrogate, this return value
>   also represents the Unicode code point of value.

Answer (score 1):

Строка - это последовательная коллекция символов, используемая для представления текста. Предложу вариант конвертации строки в массив чисел через LINQ:

```
var str = "233411";
int[] array = str
    .Select(number => Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(number)))
    .ToArray(); // создаст массив из IEnumerable (результат `Select` - IEnumerable)

foreach (var number in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

На выходе получим:

> 2 
>  3
>  3
>  4
>  1
>  1

Другие числа - потому что при конвертации символа (`char`) в число (`Int32`) - получаем код символа в кодировке Unicode. [Convert char to int in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/795991/5275890). Метод [Char.GetNumericValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8) отлично подходит для преобразования указанного числового символа Unicode в число двойной точности с плавающей запятой (то есть `double`), поэтому дополнительно применяется метод [Convert.ToInt32](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8) - который преобразует заданное значение в 32-битовое целое число со знаком (то есть в `int`, он же `Int32`).

Полезные ссылки:

- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`Enumerable.ToArray`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`Char.GetNumericValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8)
- [`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Объекты char и символы Юникода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#char-objects-and-unicode-characters)